# Transform txt file to csv

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

so I have file.txt with content like this:

```
Symbol  Name    Sector  Market Cap, $K  Last    Links
 AAPL
Apple Inc
Computers and Technology
2,006,722,560
118.03
 AMGN
Amgen Inc
Medical
132,594,808
227.76
 AXP
American Express Company
Finance
91,986,280
114.24
```

and I need to make this out of it:

```
Symbol,Name,Sector,Market Cap $K,Last
AAPL,Apple Inc,Computers and Technology,2006722560,118.03
AMGN,Amgen Inc,Medical,132594808,227.76
AXP,American Express Company,Finance,91986280,114.24
```

I have tried something like this

```
sed 's/, / /g' table1.txt | tr "\t" " " | cut -d " " -f 1-6 | tr "\n" ","
```

With output

```
Symbol Name Sector Market Cap $K Last, AAPL,Apple Inc,Computers and Technology,2,006,722,560,118.03, AMGN,Amgen Inc,Medical,132,594,808,227.76, AXP,American Express Company,Finance,91,986,280,114.24,
```

but that's not what I expect and I dont know how to continue.

Comment: show us you attempt at this.

Comment: Did you mean to remove `Links` from the output?

Comment: and why the header is not comma separated but the data are, into the output.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again at https://stackoverflow.com/q/65099010/1745001? If you have a question about an answer ask it here, if you have an answer you accept then see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have tabs between column header strings:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\t"; OFS="," }
{ gsub(OFS,"") }
NR==1 {
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,"")
    numLines = NF
    $1 = $1
    print
    next
}
{
    lineNr = (NR-2) % numLines + 1
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    rec = (lineNr == 1 ? "" : rec OFS) $0
    if ( lineNr == numLines ) {
        print rec
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Symbol,Name,Sector,Market Cap $K,Last
AAPL,Apple Inc,Computers and Technology,2006722560,118.03
AMGN,Amgen Inc,Medical,132594808,227.76
AXP,American Express Company,Finance,91986280,114.24
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
$ awk '{ 
        if(NR==1){
            sub(/,/,"");    
            gsub(/   */,","); 
            print
        }
        else{ 
            if(NR%5==2){ 
                if(NR>2){print ""}
                printf "%s,",$0
            }
            else{
                printf "%s,",$0
            }
        }
    }
    END{print ""}' file
Symbol,Name,Sector,Market Cap $K,Last,Links
 AAPL,Apple Inc,Computers and Technology,2,006,722,560,118.03,
 AMGN,Amgen Inc,Medical,132,594,808,227.76,
 AXP,American Express Company,Finance,91,986,280,114.24,
```

You can add a little post-processing to remove the trailing `,` and leading spaces:

```
$ awk '{ if(NR==1){sub(/,/,""); gsub(/   */,","); print}else{ if(NR%5==2 ){ if(NR>2){print ""}printf "%s,",$0}else{printf "%s,",$0}}}END{print ""}' file | sed 's/^  *//; s/,$//'
Symbol,Name,Sector,Market Cap $K,Last,Links
AAPL,Apple Inc,Computers and Technology,2,006,722,560,118.03
AMGN,Amgen Inc,Medical,132,594,808,227.76
AXP,American Express Company,Finance,91,986,280,114.24
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -z '
    s/,//g;
     # remove all commas
    s/\n\([^[[:blank:]]\)/,\1/g;
     # replace "\n" +a non-Tab/Space char with a comma and revert back char itself
    s/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]\+/,/g;
     # replace repeated Tabs/Spaces with a comma 
' infile
```

comments-free command and also remove leading whitespaces:

```
sed -z '
    s/,//g;
    s/\n\([^[[:blank:]]\)/,\1/g;
    s/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]\+/,/g; s/\n[[:blank:]]\+/\n/g;
' infile
```